# HTML5 buffered video attribute in mootools not working

Tags: javascript, html5-video, mootools

I am currently having a problem implementing the HTML5 buffered video attribute in MooTools. This is what I currently have, it's based of this link: [Media Progress-Meter](http://jspro.brothercake.com/media-events/progress.html). Check the page source for the code.

```
var SBar = new Class({
    Binds: ['progress'],

    initialize: function (video) {
        this.video = document.id(video);

        this.build();
        this.attach();
    },

    build: function () {
        this.element = new Element('div.seekbar');
        this.bufferbar = new Element('div.buffered');

        this.element.grab(
            this.bufferbar
        );
    },

    attach: function () {
        this.video.addEvent('loadedmetadata', this.progress);
        this.video.addEvent('progress', this.progress);
    },

    detach: function () {
        this.video.removeEvent('loadedmetadata', this.progress);
        this.video.removeEvent('progress', this.buffered);
    },

    progress: function () {

        /*
         * The following code is pretty much a MooTools adaption
         * of the code used for "Media Progress-Meter".
         *
         * http://jspro.brothercake.com/media-events/progress.html
         */

        //get the buffered ranges data
        var ranges = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.video.buffered.length; i++) {
            ranges.push([
                this.video.buffered.start(i),
                this.video.buffered.end(i)
            ]);
        }

        var spans = this.bufferbar.getChildren('span');

        while (spans.length < this.video.buffered.length) {
            this.bufferbar.grab(new Element('span'));
        }

        while (spans.length > this.video.buffered.length) {
            this.bufferbar.getChildren('span').getLast().dispose();
        }

        //now iterate through the ranges and convert each set of timings
        //to a percentage position and width for the corresponding span
        for (var i = 0; i < this.video.buffered.length; i ++) {
            spans[i].style.left = Math.round ((100 / this.video.duration) * ranges[i][0]) + '%';

            spans[i].style.width = Math.round ((100 / this.video.duration) * (ranges[i][1] - ranges[i][0])) + '%';
        }
    },

    toElement: function () {
        return this.element;
    }
});
```

The whole point of this class is to mimic the time ranges spec, without using the canvas element to show the different ranges.

The problems: In Firefox (haven't tried other browsers yet), it seems to create an endless loop (crashes my browser). If there are two video elements pointing to the same source, the bufferbar for the second video wont show.

I have tried many different solutions as well as debugging using 'console.log' and none seem to work.